# Alternative to seal strips for crankshaft rear-end bearing cap/seal plate?

Tags: gasket, bearing, crankshaft, seal

My engine uses a seal strip in the crankshaft's rear end bearing cap, which also holds the seal plate. But I don't have access to such seal strips...can I just use silicon gasket maker? Or wouldn't be better: rubber strips I can cut, daub them with silicon gasket maker and then fit them?

[image]

EDIT: Sooo...after some study, I came up with this: cut several thick cardboard strips as needed (keeping in mind the head gasket will add some thickness as well), then put them together like a sandwich or plywood by applying a very thin layer of silicone gasket maker in between. Pressed it for a day and then to use it, apply gasket maker all around.

[image]

Comment: What engine are you working on? These are the strips which goes down between the block and the main bearing cap, right? They are supposed to seal this section? We aren't talking about the crankshaft seal, are we?

Comment: Yes, the strips doing down between the block and the cap...

Comment: I've read how to seal these (in other engines of the same basic design), but for the life of me, I cannot figure out where or how. There is material you use to stuff into the hole, then push silicone down in after it to seal it. Then, when it's cured, you cut it off flush with the block. I'm just not sure where I read/saw this at or I'd give you specifics.

Comment: For those who care, I presume [this is the engine the OP is working on.](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/42457/4152)

Comment: I found these are commonly called "side seals". [Here is something which might work for you.](http://store.440source.com/Silicone-Rear-Seal-End-Strips-Kit/productinfo/144-1001/)

Comment: yeah I also found that link...I see they mention "standard style paper or cardboard strips" so maybe using thick cardboard may do, of course, together with silicon gasket maker

Comment: Just remember, those strips are intended for use in a Chrysler Big Block rear cap. They will *probably* work for your engine, but there are no guarantees. I think cardboard would be a huge crap shoot, but that's just my line of thinking.

Comment: My idea is to make a sandwich of hard cardboard and gasket maker. Today I measured the thickness it needs, about 6 strips of cardboard may do. So I will experiment with making the sandwich and then press everything until the inner silicon layers cures. Today talking with a faux-mechanic (like myself :) he told me he used silicon strips made of pressure cooker's seal, on his Peugeot diesel engine, and so far, no problems (did it 2 years ago)

Answer (score 1):

I fitted this type of seal to v8s that I built - the seal works on compression and the material mix is designed not to degrade with heat / time. If you replace it with something else - you suggest rubber - then you will need to consider if the rubber will degrade or soften over time - with the consequent downtime and costs of, maybe, removing the engine. You say you cannot get them locally - could you source and order them over the internet?

Comment: I have being told also to use thick cardboard daub with gasketmaker